# what's the ASP.NET method to load a server control by parsing from a string

Tags: asp.net, servercontrol, parsecontrol

I believe I have seen a method for doing this, but I do not remember.

I am trying to load a control using something like:

```
string str = "<asp:label id=\"myLabel\" runat=\"server\" />";

Control ctrl = SomeMagicalLoadControlMethod(str);
Page.controls.add(ctrl);
```

Is there a method for this?

And yes, I am familiar with the LoadControl method, but that's not what I need.

**Update:**

The method I was thinking of was *ParseControl*.

To help anyone else out..

```
Control ctrl = ParseControl("<asp:label id=\"myLabel\" runat=\"server\" />");
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot imagine doing something like what you describe. It looks like such as horrendous thing to do that if indeed this is possible, I would rather forget that I saw it and rethink my approach.

Comment: Looks like he want to do some dynamic control stuff. But better checkout any MVC framework and eventually add a client MVC like ExtJS as well...

Comment: The method i was thinking of is ParseControl and it cant be so horrendous if its an actual method.